# Threebox adding tooltips to building layer

Tags: javascript, three.js, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, threebox

I am trying to get a marker/label/tooltip placed on top of a 3d building but cannot seem to find a solution. I've started looking at Threebox and seem to have been able to place a tooltip on the building following the [example](https://github.com/jscastro76/threebox/blob/master/examples/08-3dbuildings.html) given in Threebox docs. The issue here is this section of the example code places the popup at the bottom of the building, whereas the tooltip is at the top.

```js
function onSelectedFeatureChange(e) {
            let feature = e.detail;
            if (feature && feature.state && feature.state.select) {

                if (popup) popup.remove();

                let center = [];
                let coords = tb.getFeatureCenter(feature, null, 0);

                center.push([coords[0], coords[1]]);

                //TODO: this creates a Mapbox popup in the same coords the Threebox popup to see the difference
                popup = new mapboxgl.Popup({ offset: 0 })
                    .setLngLat(center[0].slice())
                    .setHTML('<strong>' + (feature.id || feature.type) + '</strong >')
                    .addTo(map);

                let geoJson = {
                    "geometry": feature.geometry,
                    "type": "Feature",
                    "properties": feature.properties
                }
                console.log(JSON.stringify(geoJson, null, 2))

            }


        }
```

[image]

- How can I place the popup in the same position as the tooltip?
- If I am not able to place the popup in the location of the tooltip, how can I change the value inside of the tooltip?
- If I cannot change the value inside of the tooltip, how do I add a new tooltip to the selected building? The `feature` that is returned in the `onSelectedFeatureChange` function has a `addTooltip` method, but it requires an `obj` in order to place the tooltip.